# PHP: For loop only iterates once

Tags: php, mysql, function, for-loop, iteration

I have a function, used in a php game, where there is a for loop checking room ids. Basically, the for loop only runs once, when it should run twice. The block of code below illustrates (the first for loop with $i):

```
// successful sql login & $player is correctly set with '', and all below sql
// statements execute correctly. $count is 2
function setMonstersLocation($player,$rooms_id){
if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT state FROM present WHERE player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id IS NULL AND quantity IS NULL AND rooms_id IS NOT NULL"),0) == 0){
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM present WHERE player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id > 100 AND monsters_id < 300");
    $count = mysql_result($sql,0);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT monsters_id FROM present WHERE player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id > 100 AND monsters_id < 300 ORDER BY monsters_id");
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i+= 1) {
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT monsters_id FROM present WHERE player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id > 100 AND monsters_id < 300 ORDER BY monsters_id");
        $result = mysql_result($sql,$i);
        if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM present WHERE player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id=$result AND quantity = 1"),0) == 1){
            $final = -1;
            $array[1] = $rooms_id - 1;
            $array[2] = $rooms_id + 1;
            $array[3] = $rooms_id - 100;
            $array[4] = $rooms_id + 100;
            $array[5] = $rooms_id - 200;
            $array[6] = $rooms_id - 101;
            $array[7] = $rooms_id - 99;
            $array[8] = $rooms_id - 2;
            $array[9] = $rooms_id + 200;
            $array[10] = $rooms_id + 101;
            $array[11] = $rooms_id + 99;
            $array[12] = $rooms_id + 2;
            if ($result < 200){
                for ($j = 1; $j < 5; $j+=1){
                    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM present WHERE player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id IS NOT NULL AND rooms_id={$array[$j]}");
                    $count = mysql_result($sql,0);
                    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rooms WHERE (rooms_id={$array[$j]})");
                    $roompresent = mysql_result($sql,0);
                    if ($count == 0 and $final == -1 and $roompresent == 1){
                        $final = $array[$j];
                    }
                }
            } else if ($result > 200){
                for ($k = 1; $k < 13; $k+=1){
                    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM present WHERE (player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id IS NOT NULL AND rooms_id={$array[$k]})");
                    $count = mysql_result($sql,0);
                    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rooms WHERE (rooms_id={$array[$k]})");
                    $roompresent = mysql_result($sql,0);
                    if ($count == 0 and $final == -1 and $roompresent == 1){ $final = $array[$k]; }
                }
                if ($final == -1){
                    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rooms");
                    $count = mysql_result($sql,0);
                    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT rooms_id FROM rooms");
                    for ($l = 0; $l < $count; $l+=1){
                        $rooms = mysql_query($sql,$l);
                        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM present WHERE player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id IS NOT NULL AND rooms_id=$rooms");
                        if (mysql_result($sql,0) == 0 and $final == -1){ $final = $rooms; }
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($final != -1){ $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE present SET rooms_id=$final WHERE player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id=$result;"); } 
            else { $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE present SET rooms_id=-1 WHERE player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id=$result");}
        }
    }
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE present SET state = 1 WHERE player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id IS NULL AND quantity IS NULL AND rooms_id IS NOT NULL");
} else {
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE present SET state = 0 WHERE player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id IS NULL AND quantity IS NULL AND rooms_id IS NOT NULL");
}
```

}

while $count is 2, the for loop only runs once. I've verified this by adding 1 to a value in a mysql table every time the for loop runs. The value only increases by once.

The if statement at the top, is to run the function every other tick.

Comment: You have used $count variable as main loop controller as well as inner variable value count inside the for loop. Cross check it.

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They are obsolete. Use PDO and perform queries using prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition part of the for loop is evaluated on each iteration of the loop, so you can't change the value of `$count` inside the main loop. You need to change the variable names to something more meaningful.

Try this:

```
// successful sql login & $player is correctly set with '', and all below sql
// statements execute correctly. $count is 2
function setMonstersLocation($player,$rooms_id){
if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT state FROM present WHERE player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id IS NULL AND quantity IS NULL AND rooms_id IS NOT NULL"),0) == 0){
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM present WHERE player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id > 100 AND monsters_id < 300");
    // Note here I've changed $count to $playerCount, because it is a count of the
    // number of players.
    $playerCount = mysql_result($sql,0);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT monsters_id FROM present WHERE player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id > 100 AND monsters_id < 300 ORDER BY monsters_id");
    for ($i = 0; $i < $playerCount; $i+= 1) {
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT monsters_id FROM present WHERE player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id > 100 AND monsters_id < 300 ORDER BY monsters_id");
        $result = mysql_result($sql,$i);
        if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM present WHERE player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id=$result AND quantity = 1"),0) == 1){
            $final = -1;
            $array[1] = $rooms_id - 1;
            $array[2] = $rooms_id + 1;
            $array[3] = $rooms_id - 100;
            $array[4] = $rooms_id + 100;
            $array[5] = $rooms_id - 200;
            $array[6] = $rooms_id - 101;
            $array[7] = $rooms_id - 99;
            $array[8] = $rooms_id - 2;
            $array[9] = $rooms_id + 200;
            $array[10] = $rooms_id + 101;
            $array[11] = $rooms_id + 99;
            $array[12] = $rooms_id + 2;
            if ($result < 200){
                for ($j = 1; $j < 5; $j+=1){
                    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM present WHERE player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id IS NOT NULL AND rooms_id={$array[$j]}");
                    // Note here I've change $count to $presentCount, because you're
                    // counting the number of presents? (Whatever presents are)
                    $presentCount = mysql_result($sql,0);
                    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rooms WHERE (rooms_id={$array[$j]})");
                    $roompresent = mysql_result($sql,0);
                    if ($presentCount == 0 and $final == -1 and $roompresent == 1){
                        $final = $array[$j];
                    }
                }
            } else if ($result > 200){
                for ($k = 1; $k < 13; $k+=1){
                    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM present WHERE (player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id IS NOT NULL AND rooms_id={$array[$k]})");
                    // You can use $presentCount again here, because it's a 
                    // different code block to the previous one.
                    // This doesn't mean its in a different SCOPE, however.
                    $presentCount = mysql_result($sql,0);
                    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rooms WHERE (rooms_id={$array[$k]})");
                    $roompresent = mysql_result($sql,0);
                    if ($presentCount == 0 and $final == -1 and $roompresent == 1){ $final = $array[$k]; }
                }
                if ($final == -1){
                    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rooms");
                    // Note here I've change $count to $roomsCount, because you're 
                    // counting the number of rooms.
                    $roomsCount = mysql_result($sql,0);
                    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT rooms_id FROM rooms");
                    for ($l = 0; $l < $roomsCount; $l+=1){
                        $rooms = mysql_query($sql,$l);
                        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM present WHERE player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id IS NOT NULL AND rooms_id=$rooms");
                        if (mysql_result($sql,0) == 0 and $final == -1){ $final = $rooms; }
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($final != -1){ $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE present SET rooms_id=$final WHERE player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id=$result;"); } 
            else { $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE present SET rooms_id=-1 WHERE player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id=$result");}
        }
    }
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE present SET state = 1 WHERE player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id IS NULL AND quantity IS NULL AND rooms_id IS NOT NULL");
} else {
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE present SET state = 0 WHERE player = $player AND items_id IS NULL AND monsters_id IS NULL AND quantity IS NULL AND rooms_id IS NOT NULL");
}
```